# Сайт не работает при отключении проверки подлинности Windows в MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Создал новый проект MVC5 с пустым шаблоном, добавил необходимые файлы и код. При запуске долго думает ,но ничего не выводит. Включаю в свойстах проекта проверку подлинности Windows - всё работает. В конфиге прописал impersonate=false и не помогло. Нужна ли эта проверка, а также что делает анонимная проверка подлинности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему оказалось быстрее всего решить переустановкой windows 10 и VS2015.